# Is it possible to find usage of java classes or methods in VIM?

Tags: java, vim

Or one shouldn't use vim for such goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the integration of `exuberant-ctags` with `vim` for that purpose. It handles `java` quite well.

See this [article](http://blog.vinceliu.com/2007/08/vim-tips-for-java-2-using-exuberant.html) for example.

Comment: I didn't see anything about "finding usage of classes and methods" there, only looking up definitions. Which the question does not seem to be about.

Comment: Right, this does not exactly solve this need, but the [faq](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#12) gives a good lead.

Answer (score 1):

You should try out the [Vim Taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) plugin; it allows you to browse between source code tags in a variety of languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it is possible, wither it is easy and how to do it are different questions.
The VI and there for VIM philosophy tends to simplicity and lightness. IDE features like find usage tend to slow down startup and increase memory footprint, so I would expect to find very few VIM plugins to do this.

I would suggest loading up your classes in an IDE ( like the free eclipse ) or if you much prefer command line try emacs as this gets much closer to a command line IDE then VIM.

Comment: Looks like a bit of a non-answer to me. Your answer could be summarized as "I think it might be possible, but I don't know how. Anyway, use something else" :)

Comment: @Sam - the question included "Or one shouldn't use vim for such goals?" I was more answering that question then the question in the title.